# Why am I unable to retrieve the email ID using User.Identity.Email with UseOktaMvc authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, okta

I am using UseOktaMvc in my ASP.net C# and authenticating Okta, Once logged in i am only able to get logged in user name by User.Identity.Name. I am not able to get the Email Id. How do i retrive the email ID

My Code: Startup

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
          app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

           

            app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
            {
                OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
               
                AuthorizationServerId = String.Empty,
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],

                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email" },

            });
        }
```

and my Default page has

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {


                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                  new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home.aspx" },
                  OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            }
        }
```

In my home page i am unable to get the email id.I have been searching various forms for the answer but nothing helped

In my home page i am unable to get the email id.I have been searching various forms for the answer but nothing helped